# Comparing two tables and get the result of one of the tables

Tags: mysql, compare

I have two tables. One table contains all the users information. The other table contains a record of each time a user logged into our system.
What I need to show is how many users did not login to the system.

We have 1613 records. 262 users logged in over a given time period. The compare query should display the difference but my query does not. It returns 411(where this comes from , I have no idea) I am clearly doing something wrong.

this is my query.

```
 SELECT s.id 
,s.first_name 
, s.surname 
, s.email 
, s.`Status`
,date_format(s.subscription_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as subscription_start 
,date_format(s.subscription_expiry_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as subscription_expiry 
FROM user s LEFT JOIN user_log eul ON s.id=eul.userid 
WHERE eul.userid IS NULL
and (s.status = 'Live' and s.activated = 1) 
and s.payment > 0 
and s.subscription_start_date < now() 
and s.subscription_expiry_date > now()
```

I hope this makes sense.

Ok. 
**Below is updated info**

This is the original query. This pulls back all the people who have logged into our system. With a count next to their names. This data is for the month of June. I need to know who didn't login within the month of June. Does this make sense?

```
select 
s.first_name 
, s.surname 
, s.email 
,date_format(s.subscription_start_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as subscription_start 
,date_format(s.subscription_expiry_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as subscription_expiry 
, count(*) as count 
, concat(year(eul.date_created), '-', lpad(month(eul.date_created), 2, 0)) as date 
from user_log eul 
INNER join user s on (s.id = eul.userid) 
Where s.payment > 0 and s.subscription_start_date <= {d '2018-06-30'} and s.subscription_expiry_date > now() 
and (s.status = 'Live' and s.activated = 1) 
and eul.date_created >= {d '2018-06-01'} 
and eul.date_created <= {d '2018-06-30'} 
group by email, concat(year(eul.date_created), '-', lpad(month(eul.date_created), 2, 0))
```

thanks in advance.
Andrea

Comment: @itavq that is the exact part that should do the work.

Comment: I suspect you have wrong expectations. How did you count *1613 records. 262 users logged* ? What does it mean to you?  You said *in over a given time period* but your query has no specific **period**. Your query just selects all active subscriptions. So your goal is not clear, your raw data is not provided. Try to set sqlfiddle with data sample and show your expected output. Show your table schemas

Comment: Please add a table schema for both tables. Your query initially looks correct.

Comment: I  think my other query may be wrong but I will have to check again or as Alex said - my expectations are wrong. I will add some mre info which should make this more clear.

Comment: Updated info added. This should hopefully make sense.